# Phonegap Developer App and Phonegap Build have different behavior

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build, phonegap

I`m developing mobile app using phonegap build for android and iOS platforms. iOS version looks fine and identically both on build version and Phonegap Developer App. Also Phonegap Developer App works in the same way for Android. 
But when I install phonegap build's apk-file to Android, some html-layout for specific div gets wrong scale, as if I wrote another width in css for this div. But the rest part of my application looks ok.
The most confusing thing for me in this situation is different appearance of Phonegap Build app and phonegap develop app. I tried to remove all plugins from config.xml to check if they influence somehow to app's behavior, but the result was the same. So my question is: why there may be distinctions in behavior of build and developer versions?

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="myapp" ios-CFBundleIdentifier="myapp" version="1.0.3" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
<name>Test App</name>
<description>
    Hello World sample application that responds to the deviceready event.
</description>
<author email="support@phonegap.com" href="http://phonegap.com">
    PhoneGap Team
</author>
<content src="index.html" />
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
<preference name="Orientation" value="portrait" />
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
<edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml" mode="overwrite" target="/manifest/application/activity[@android:name='MainActivity']">
    <activity gap:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" gap:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
</edit-config>
<branch-config>
    <branch-key value="some_key" />
    <uri-scheme value="some_value" />
    <link-domain value="some_domain" />
    <ios-team-release value="some_value" />
</branch-config>
</widget>
```

[It looks ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AuR4.png)
[It looks wrong (the circle)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYOtU.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you did not use [responsive](https://getbootstrap.com/) design, you will need to reduce the size of the image, as this happens on every different device.

Comment: it`s css only, not an image (except the image inside of this div, but scale of image is ok, the rest part of this has wrong size)

Comment: @E.Dn Did you used responsive design?

Comment: No, I didn't, I used absolute values (px). Does it really matter? I can't understand why it looks ok when I test the application via phonegap developer app, but looks different on build version. Doesn't it have to be exactly the same thing?

Comment: It is advisable to use responsive design, just because the user will come to the tablet and everything will be mixed. Try it just with the tablet. Or open it in your web browser. Also try this, maybe it's going to fix your problem; in config.xml `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, target-densitydpi=medium-dpi, user-scalable=0" />`

Comment: I'm already using this tag in my index.html. I'll remember the point about responsive design, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is with the HTML content size, it sounds as a **viewport** issue. All manufacturers tend to alter the Android webview engine, so to ensure your app looks the same on most devices you must add this meta-tag to the `head` section of your `index.html` file:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height" />
```

This means that:

- User cannot zoom inside your app
- The initial zoom is 100% (means no zoom)
- The viewport width (page horizontal size) is the same as the device width
- The viewport height is the same as the device height

To prevent issues like this, you should create your app with the sample `index.html` generated by Cordova when you create a new app using the command line interface. This creates an app with an index.html and CSS file with the proper structure to ensure it will look (mostly) identical on every device.